# try/except in django, good practices

Tags: django, exception, try-catch

This part of code represents a index of my web page 
eg: 127.0.0.1:8000/

```
def IndexView(request):
    try:
        profile = request.user.get_profile() 
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'request': request,},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('index.html',
                  {'request': request, 'profile' : profile},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Why i'm still getting this error on debug?

AttributeError at /
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_profile'

thanks in advance

Comment: Change that User.DoesNotExist to an AttributeError and you're in the clear.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this check:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index_view(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        profile = request.user.get_profile()
        return render(request,'index.html',{'profile': profile})
    else:
        return redirect('login/')
```

Or, you can use the built-in decorator which ensures that your view is only called with a logged in user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def index_view(request):

    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'profile': profile})
```

If you use the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) you need to make sure you have a [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-LOGIN_URL) setting that points to the view that handles the login form for your site. By default this is `/accounts/login/`

I changed the method name to lowercase as CamelCase is usually for classes in Python. Also, you don't need two return statements since you are rendering the same template. Instead, in your `index.html` template you can do:

```
{% if profile %}
    You have a profile!
{% else %}
    You don't
{% endif %}
```

Tips and tricks with authentication are listed at the [authentication entry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) in the documentation.

Comment: [Anonimous User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users) is a class that implements the django.contrib.auth.models.User interface, with these differences:is_anonymous() returns True instead of False. You should use `request.user.is_authenticated()` check.

Answer (score 0):

Because a user isn't currently logged in. When you call get_profile it gets called on a default user provided by Django called AnonymousUser which doesn't have a get_profile method as it isn't a real user. It doesn't throw an exception I am assuming and hence you get an error.
Try the same thing after logging in and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because this specific user is not logged in.

To prevent the error either use the `@login_required` decorator just over your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def IndexView(request):
    ...
```

or:

```
def IndexView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated(): #check to use if user is logged in
        try:
            profile = request.user.get_profile() 
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'request': request,},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        return render_to_response('index.html',
                      {'request': request, 'profile' : profile},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a `User.DoesNotExist` error, but instead the code is throwing an `AttributeError`.  This is because `request.user` is a real object -- an `AnonymousUser` object -- and accessing it does not cause an error, but an `AnonymousUser` has no profile.

Use the `@login_required` decorator instead, or catch the `AttributeError`, or adjust your code so that it actually does throw `User.DoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user is authenticated before you try to pull the profile through `get_profile`.  You can also simplify your code quite a bit:

```
def IndexView(request):
    profile = request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.get_profile() 

    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              {'request': request, 'profile': profile},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You don't need the except, because the `User` with always be there.

Comment: You still need the except if you aren't checking whether the user has get_profile as an attribute.

Comment: @AlexHart: That only would happen if you have an issue with your signals that should be creating a new profile for each new User.

Comment: If it's an AnonymousUser object, it isn't a User object, and won't have the get_profile method to begin with, which is the issue he was having in the first place.

Comment: @AlexHart: An `AnonymousUser`'s `is_authenticated` always returns `False`.

Comment: @sdloan and yet the way he wrote it he still wants anons to be able to access the page. While he could and really should replace the try except block with an if, adding login_required as some suggested would change the functionality of the view.

Comment: @AlexHart: With my code an anonymous user would still be able to access the page without using a `login_required` decorator.  If the user is not authenticated, it will short circuit, and the `profile` variable will be false in the template.

Comment: Yes now that I take the time to read I didn't notice the and statement before.

Answer (score -1):

Just to let you know, that's not very dry code.

check it:

```
def index_view(request):
    context_data = {'request': request}
    try:
        context_data.update('profile': request.user.get_profile())
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return render_to_response('index.html', context_data,
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also, I'd double check and make sure request isn't already included in context.  You may not have to specifically put it into context here.

EDIT: Forgot to pass context_data to render_to_response, example updated.